# How to unplug these connectors on 80's amp/receiver

Tags: pcb

I'm trying to unplug these connectors to get access to the lcd display.

Do I need a special tool? I tried but to no avail. The little ones seem fragile. What is the name of these connectors?

[image: small connector]

[image: bigger connector]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen ribbon cable connectors like that before. They were originally very common on imported electronics. They are connectors but but not in the sense as most people would think, they do not unplug. They made it easy to connect ribbon type cable to a PCB. If you look on the bottom they will be soldered to the PCB with no way to release the wire from them. The only way to remove them is to unsolder them from the PCB. The PCB board shown in the picture is relatively fragile and will not take much abuse desoldering. If you are not experienced in desoldering through hole components consider if you can afford to lose the unit or have a friend do it for you.

Comment: Yes I think you are right. I finally managed to release the upper part and it did look like the wires wrre soldered to the board and the pseudo connector is only to help keep it in place. Thanks for taking the time and confirming this. I will not mess with it. It's in my 1988 Marantz receiver. Now in the process of finding a new fluorescent display.

Answer (score 1):

The connectors might be of the type where you can release the wire. The outer shell can be pulled up when releases the clamp on the wires. The cable assembly can then be withdrawn easily.

To reconect is the reverse - insert the cable assembly. Push down on the outer shell until it locks.

I'm not sure of the official name for these types of connectors. Wire clamping??